# How to get unique items from an array?

Tags: java, arrays

I am Java beginner, I found a few topics regarding this theme, but none of them worked for me.
I have an array like this:

```
int[] numbers = {1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 5};
```

and I would need to get this output:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

Every item from that array just once.

But how to get it?

Comment: I vote up because they have shut down your previous attempt http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14656208/array-of-unique-elements for a false reason. It is really a question. Just your title is wrong. It asks for count whereas the body requests for the items.

Answer (score 13):

The simpliest solution without writing your own algorithm:

```
Integer[] numbers = {1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 5};
Set<Integer> uniqKeys = new TreeSet<Integer>();
uniqKeys.addAll(Arrays.asList(numbers));
System.out.println("uniqKeys: " + uniqKeys);
```

Set interface guarantee uniqueness of values. TreeSet additionally sorts this values.

Comment: Technically, a `TreeSet` is giving you more than you would need to solve this particular problem; a `HashSet` would suffice.

Comment: @hertzsprung I guess the `LinkedHashSet` will be better for this case.

Comment: What if I've 2D array?

Comment: @NoOne use the loop through the rows. Inside the loop do call addAll for every row.

Answer (score 8):

You can use a [`Set<Integer>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) and save lot of time since it holds unique elements. If you aren't allowed to use any class from Java Collections, sort the array and count the unique elements. You can sort the array manually or use [`Arrays#sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28int%5b%5d%29).

I'll post the `Set<Integer>` code:

```
int[] numbers = {1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 5};
Set<Integer> setUniqueNumbers = new LinkedHashSet<Integer>();
for(int x : numbers) {
    setUniqueNumbers.add(x);
}
for(Integer x : setUniqueNumbers) {
    System.out.println(x);
}
```

Note that I prefer to use [`LinkedHashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) as Set implementation since it maintains the order of how the elements were inserted. This means, if your array was `{2 , 1 , 2}` then the output will be `2, 1` and not `1, 2`.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer Luiggi. This belongs to the basic exercises, so I believe using a something more beginner-like is required. However, I am trying to implement your sample, but getting this error: `Set cannot be resolved to a type. LinkedHashSet cannot be resolved to a type` Do I miss any library or something like that? Thank you

Comment: @user984621 you need to import those classes from `java.util` package. Below the `package your.package;` sentence, add `import java.util.*;`.

Comment: Do you know why you can't use <int> instead of  <Integer> when writing sets?

Comment: @Chi-YoungJeffreyLii in Java, `int` is a primitive type and generics are supported for reference types (classes and interfaces) only. `Integer` is a class wrapper for the primitive `int` type.

Comment: What's the rationale behind that I mean. It seems like using primitive data types would be easier for some computations.

Comment: @Chi-YoungJeffreyLii that's how the language is designed. If you're looking for more info, please post a new question about it.

Answer (score 5):

In Java 8:

```
    final int[] expected = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    final int[] numbers = { 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 5 };

    final int[] distinct = Arrays.stream(numbers)
        .distinct()
        .toArray();

    Assert.assertArrayEquals(Arrays.toString(distinct), expected, distinct);

    final int[] unorderedNumbers = { 5, 1, 2, 1, 4, 3, 5 };

    final int[] distinctOrdered = Arrays.stream(unorderedNumbers)
        .sorted()
        .distinct()
        .toArray();

    Assert.assertArrayEquals(Arrays.toString(distinctOrdered), expected, distinctOrdered);
```

Comment: Do you know if `Arrays.stream(x).distinct().sorted().toArray()` would perform better than `Arrays.stream(x).sorted().dictinct().toArray()`? ie. Presumably the former would have fewer entries to sort?

Comment: For what it's worth using JMH on the code above:

Benchmark                                    Mode  Samples       Score      Error  Units
distinctSorted   thrpt      200  465730.014 ± 2127.406  ops/s
sortedDistinct   thrpt      200  467130.970 ± 6364.848  ops/s

Answer (score 3):

```
//Running total of distinct integers found
int distinctIntegers = 0;

for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++)
{
    //Get the next integer to check
    int thisInt = array[j];

    //Check if we've seen it before (by checking all array indexes below j)
    boolean seenThisIntBefore = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < j; i++)
    {
        if (thisInt == array[i])
        {
            seenThisIntBefore = true;
        }
    }

    //If we have not seen the integer before, increment the running total of distinct integers
    if (!seenThisIntBefore)
    {
        distinctIntegers++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Below code will print unique integers have a look:

```
printUniqueInteger(new int[]{1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 5});


static void printUniqueInteger(int array[]){
    HashMap<Integer, String> map = new HashMap();

    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        map.put(array[i], "test");
    }

    for(Integer key : map.keySet()){
        System.out.println(key);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple **Hashing** will be far *efficient* and *faster* than any Java inbuilt function:

```
public class Main 
{
    static int HASH[];
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int[] numbers = {1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 5};
        HASH=new int[100000];
        for(int i=0;i<numbers.length;i++)
        {
            if(HASH[numbers[i]]==0)
            {
                System.out.print(numbers[i]+",");
                HASH[numbers[i]]=1;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**Time Complexity**: O(N), where N=numbers.length

**[DEMO](http://ideone.com/pnmWvq)**

Answer (score 2):

```
public class Practice {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(3,7,3,-1,2,3,7,2,15,15));
        countUnique(list);
}

public static void countUnique(List<Integer> list){
    Collections.sort(list);
    Set<Integer> uniqueNumbers = new HashSet<Integer>(list);
    System.out.println(uniqueNumbers.size());
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

In JAVA8, you can simply use

> stream()

and

> distinct()

to get unique elements.

```
intArray = Arrays.stream(intArray).distinct().toArray();
```

Comment: and if you want that array to be sorted, use Arrays.sort(intArray); after getting unique elements!

Answer (score 1):

There is an easier way to get a distinct list:

```
Integer[] intArray = {1,2,3,0,0,2,4,0,2,5,2};
List<Integer> intList = Arrays.asList(intArray);          //To List
intList = new ArrayList<>(new LinkedHashSet<>(intList));  //Distinct
Collections.sort(intList);                                //Optional Sort
intArray = intList.toArray(new Integer[0]);               //Back to array
```

Outputs:

```
1 2 3 0 0 2 4 0 2 5 2   //Array
1 2 3 0 0 2 4 0 2 5 2   //List
1 2 3 0 4 5             //Distinct List
0 1 2 3 4 5             //Distinct Sorted List
0 1 2 3 4 5             //Distinct Sorted Array
```

See [jDoodle Example](http://jdoodle.com/a/1rfr)

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
    int[] numbers = {1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 5};
    ArrayList<Integer> store = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // so the size can vary

    for (int n = 0; n < numbers.length; n++){
        if (!store.contains(numbers[n])){ // if numbers[n] is not in store, then add it
            store.add(numbers[n]);
        }
    }
    numbers = new int[store.size()];
    for (int n = 0; n < store.size(); n++){
        numbers[n] = store.get(n);
    }
```

Integer and int can be (almost) used interchangeably. This piece of code takes your array "numbers" and changes it so that all duplicate numbers are lost. If you want to sort it, you can add `Collections.sort(store);` before `numbers = new int[store.size()]`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you've solved your issue yet, but my code would be:

```
    int[] numbers = {1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 5};
    int x = numbers.length;
    int[] unique = new int[x];
    int p = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        int temp = numbers[i];
        int b = 0;
        for(int y = 0; y < x; y++)
        {
            if(unique[y] != temp)
            {
               b++;
            }
        }
        if(b == x)
        {
            unique[p] = temp;
            p++;
        }
    }
    for(int a = 0; a < p; a++)
    {
        System.out.print(unique[a]);
        if(a < p-1)
        {
            System.out.print(", ");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String s1[]=  {"hello","hi","j2ee","j2ee","sql","jdbc","hello","jdbc","hybernet","j2ee"};

int c=0;

for(int i=0;i<s1.length;i++)
{
    for(int j=i+1;j<s1.length;j++)
    {
    if(s1[i]==(s1[j]) )
    {
        c++;
    }
    }
        if(c==0)
         {
            System.out.println(s1[i]);
         }
            else
             {
            c=0;
              } 
            }
         }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

To find out unique data:

```
public class Uniquedata 
 {
 public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
int c=0;

String s1[]={"hello","hi","j2ee","j2ee","sql","jdbc","hello","jdbc","hybernet","j2ee","hello","hello","hybernet"};

for(int i=0;i<s1.length;i++)
{
    for(int j=i+1;j<s1.length;j++)
    {
    if(s1[i]==(s1[j]) )
    {
        c++;
        s1[j]="";
    }}
        if(c==0)
        {
            System.out.println(s1[i]);
        }
            else
            {
                s1[i]="";
            c=0;    
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
Object[] array = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(numbers)).toArray();
```

Comment: For code, you can wrap it in backticks, so it is formatted like code
`some code`

Comment: '<>' operator is not allowed for source level below 1.7, so it'll need to be typeset for lower JDK versions as HashSet<some_class>

Answer (score 0):

Here is my piece of code using counting sort (partially)

Output is a sorted array consiting of unique elements

```
    void findUniqueElementsInArray(int arr[]) {
    int[] count = new int[256];
    int outputArrayLength = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (count[arr[i]] < 1) {
            count[arr[i]] = count[arr[i]] + 1;
            outputArrayLength++;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < 256; i++) {
        count[i] = count[i] + count[i - 1];
    }
    int[] sortedArray = new int[outputArrayLength];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        sortedArray[count[arr[i]] - 1] = arr[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < sortedArray.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(sortedArray[i]);
    }
}
```

Reference - discovered this solution while
trying to solve a [problem from HackerEarth](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/algorithms/sorting/counting-sort/practice-problems/algorithm/shil-and-birthday-present/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are a Java programmer, I recommend you to use this.
It will work.

```
public class DistinctElementsInArray {

//Print all distinct elements in a given array without any duplication

    public static void printDistinct(int arr[], int n) {

        // Pick all elements one by one
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

            // Check if the picked element is already existed
            int j;
            for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
                if (arr[i] == arr[j])
                    break;

            // If not printed earlier, then print it
            if (i == j)
                System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int array[] = { 4, 5, 9, 5, 4, 6, 6, 5, 4, 10, 6, 4, 5, 3, 8, 4, 8, 3 };
        // 4 - 5 5 - 4 9 - 1 6 - 3 10 - 1 3 - 2 8 - 2

        int arrayLength = array.length;
        printDistinct(array, arrayLength);

    }
}
```

Comment: Copied from GeeksforGeeks

Answer (score -1):

```
public class DistinctArray {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
     int num[]={1,2,5,4,1,2,3,5};
     for(int i =0;i<num.length;i++)
     {
         boolean isDistinct=false;
         for(int j=0;j<i;j++)
         {
             if(num[j]==num[i])
             {
                 isDistinct=true;
                 break;
             }
         }
         if(!isDistinct)
         {
             System.out.print(num[i]+" ");
         }
     }
    }

}
```