# counting number of unique elements

Tags: java, arrays, duplicates

Hi so I am supposed to count the number of unique elements after an array sort excluding duplicates but i'm getting the wrong output.

```
In in = new In(args[0]);
int[] whitelist = in.readAllInts();
Arrays.sort(whitelist);

int count = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < whitelist.length; i++) {
       if (whitelist[i] == whitelist[count]) {
           count++;
       }
   }
while (!StdIn.isEmpty()) {
    int key = StdIn.readInt();
    rank(key, whitelist);
}
   System.out.println(count);
```

}
}

expected output: java InstrumentedBinarySearch tinyW.txt < tinyT.txt

65

got: 16

Did i count the number of duplicates or something?

Comment: Can you provide more code to illustrate the problem? What is `whitelist`?

Comment: Run the program in your head (acting like you are the computer) and you might see why it doesn't work.

Comment: this is the main method

Comment: This has been answered before: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15752235/1980909

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java - how to get count of unique items from an array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15752180/java-how-to-get-count-of-unique-items-from-an-array)

Comment: count seems to be used wrong. Introduce a variable "last value". then you can do if !(whitelist[i]==latVal) lastVal=whitelist[i] else count++; inside the for.

Answer (score 0):

```
  int flag = 0;
  int count = 0;
       for (int i = 0; i < whitelist.length; i++) //Element to be checked for
  {
           for (int j=0; j< whitelist.length ; j++) //Loop that goes through the whole array 
       {
               if (whitelist[i] == whitelist[j]) //checks if there are duplicates
               {
                   flag++; // count
               }
       }
    if( flag==1) //There should be only 1 instance of the element in the array and that is the element itself
    { 
       System.out.println(whitelist[i]); //displays unique element
       count++; // Keeps count 
    }
 }
```

Comment: This was my answer before you edited the question. This code will find the unique elements in an array.

Comment: I've added the comments to explain each line. the OPs code uses whitelist[count] which makes no sense since the count is the number of duplicates count, and it does not browse through the rest of the array the same way j variable works in my code.
Hope it helps.

Comment: this method is giving me the answer 10 instead of 65

Answer (score 0):

This algorithm counts how many different unique numbers there are in the array. A number appearing more than once will only count for 1. I am assuming this is what you mean, as opposed to "numbers which appear exactly once".

There is a more trivial way to do it, as proposed in another answer, but it requires a nested for-loop and therefore executes in quadratic complexity. My algorithm below attempts to solve the problem in linear time proportional to the array size.

```
int uniquesFound = 0;

// Assume that array is sorted, so duplicates would be next to another.
// If we find duplicates, such as 12223, we will only count its last instance (i.e. the last '2')
for (int i = 0; i < whitelist.length; i++) {

    // If we are at the last element, we know we can count it
    if (i != whitelist.length - 1) {
        if (whitelist[i] != whitelist[i+1]) {
            uniquesFound++;
        }
        else {
            // Nothing! If they are the same, move to the next step element
        }
    } else {
        uniquesFound++;
    }
}
```

For instance, given the array:

{1,2,3} this will yield 3 because there are 3 unique numbers

{1,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5} this will yield 5 because there are still 5 unique numbers

Comment: to be more clear, im supposed to remove the duplicate keys in the whitelist after the sort. So the number of keys examined should be smaller than when the duplicates weren't removed in which according to your logic it seems correct. But its not producing any results, just blank

Comment: If your sorting step also happens to remove duplicate keys, then the number of unique items is simply equal to the length of the array. This is because if you remove duplicate keys, the only thing left in the array are unique numbers.

Comment: How do i print the number of unique keys in this case?

Comment: If you're telling me that whitelist is sorted and has been stripped of all duplicate keys, then the number of unique keys is the length of the whitelist array. Just print whitelist.length. 

If you're still confused, why don't you give me an example and tell me what is in whitelist and what the answer should be.

Comment: thats weird your solution is giving me the same answer as the one i have posted.

Comment: Could you provide an example? Tell me what is inside whitelist, what the actual result is and what the expected result is.

Comment: Well it I am supposed to read numbers from the file TinyT.txt which contains the numbers {23,50,10,99,18,23,98,84,11,10,48,77,13,54,98,77,77,68} and add those numbers to the list contained in TinyW.txt { 84, 48 ,68, 10, 18, 98, 12, 23, 54, 57, 48, 33, 16, 77, 11, 29. I've checked the duplicates myself and removed them and the number of unique results is 18 but the expected result is 65. I'm not too sure what whitelist contains because i assume it is the combination of both files

Comment: How can the number of unique items be 65 if there are not even 65 numbers in the sum of both of your files?

Answer (score 0):

First let's take a look at your loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < whitelist.length; i++) {
    if (whitelist[i] == whitelist[count]) {
        count++;
    }
}
```

You should be comparing consecutive elements in the list, like whitelist[0] == whitelist[1]?, whitelist[1] == whitelist[2]?, whitelist[3] == whitelist[4]?, etc. Doing `whitelist[i] == whitelist[count]` makes no sense in this context.

Now you have two options:

a. Increment your counter when you find two consecutive elements that are equal and subtract the result from the total size of the array:

```
for (int i = 0; i < whitelist.length - 1; i++) {
    if (whitelist[i] == whitelist[i + 1]) {
        count++;
    }
}
int result = whitelist.length - count;
```

b. Change the condition to count the transitions between consecutive elements that are not equal. Since you are counting the number of transitions, you need to add `1` to `count` in the end to get the number of unique elements in the array:

```
for (int i = 0; i < whitelist.length - 1; i++) {
    if (whitelist[i] != whitelist[i + 1]) {
         count++;
    }
}
int result = count + 1;
```

Note that, in both cases, we loop only until `whitelist.length - 1`, so that `whitelist[i + 1]` does not go out of bounds.